# Is not the width for javascript 'screen.availWidth' the same as CSS3 media query max-width?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, media

I have been experimenting with a simple web page in my mobile phone (see specification about browser etc at the bottom) with these two media queries:

```
@media all and (max-width: 979px) { ... css setting a background color for a certain element
@media all and (min-width: 980px) { ... css setting another background color for the same element
```

The values used above 979/980 I have found through experimentation, i.e. these seem to be the value for my mobile, i.e. if I increase or decrease these two values I notice that the other one of them become applied instead.

However, I do not think I should have to experiment to figure out these border values and instead thought I should be able to use the following javascript:

```
 document.write('<br>your resolution is ' + screen.availWidth + ' , ' + screen.availHeight);
```

The above detected javascript width value is more than hundred pixels different from (854 instead of 979) the values actually working in the media queries.

So, my question is how can I use javascript (or server sided code) to figure out the device width, with a value useful in media queries, considering that 'screen.availWidth' obviously does not work (and 'screen.width' neither works) ?

My mobile phone is Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc S, and the operating system I am using is Android 4.0.4.
I have done this experimentation with the following three browsers:
- Chrome 18.0.1025.166
- Firefox 14.0
- "Opera/9.80  version/12.00" (not sure about what the 9.80 means but I guess the version is 12.00, and this string I got from javascript 'navigator.userAgent')

The Chrome browser displays these width/height value with the above mentioned javascript: 480 x 854 or 854 x 480 (depending on whether I hold it in portrait or landscape)
The Firefox browser displays the same width/height value as Chrome above.
The Opera browser displays width/height 854 x 439 in landscape and 480 x 658 in portrait.

However, when trying to apply CSS3 media query as described above, then all these browser seem to use the value 979 instead of 854.

Comment: Server-side: No. Client-side: Check out the many media-query-emulation libraries on the web!